# How to apply multiple filters on TSQLQuery

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, fpc

Singular filter on some column works, for example:

```
SQLQuery.Filter := 'ColumnName="some_filtered_text"'; // OK
```

But how to apply filter to many columns?

For example this doesn't work:

```
SQLQuery.Filter := 'ColumnName1="some_filtered_text1",
    ColumnName2="some_filtered_text2"'; // Exception
```

It raises exception: "TApplication.HandleException Operator/function missing".

Comment: It is like SQL `where` condition. Use `and` instead of comma: `ColumnName1="some_filtered_text1" and ColumnName2="some_filtered_text2"`

Comment: @Abelisto: this solves my problem. Thanks! It's so easy...